# Dustjs-linkedin pass variable in nested loop

Tags: node.js, dust.js

I am trying to pass a variable from the first loop into the next. Why am I doing this? Well they both have the same key. Here is an example of trying to pass the index from the first loop into the second. Both values end up being the $idx of the second loop. How can this be done?

```
{#first}
  {#second firstIDX="{$idx}"}
    {firstIDX} : {$idx}<br>
  {/second}
{/first}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using the following (dot notation and no quotes):

```
{#first}
  {#second firstIDX=$idx firstID=._id}
    {firstIDX} : {$idx}<br>
    {firstID} : {_id}<br>
  {/second}
{/first}
```